# My ubuntu shows the error :"Segmentation fault (core dumped)" while installing django in virtual environment

Tags: django, ubuntu, pip, python-venv

[image: Screenshot of the error]

"Segmentation fault (core dumped)" is shown for all operations in the virtual environment

Comment: think this error is not related to Django but from OS. You can find the answer in this forum. [https://askubuntu.com/questions/690565/how-to-resolve-segmentation-fault-core-dumped].

Comment: Which version of python and django are you using? Did you do an upgrade in the django or python version?

Comment: I had this problem after reinstalling and upgrading a Mac OS. It rendered all my existing virtualenvs unusable. Have you tried deleting the current virtualenv, creating a new one and installing the requirements again?